# How long does a self-signed certificate's "Proceed Anyway" exception last in Google Chrome?

Tags: https, certificate, google-chrome

As is usual with most web development, I have a web server using a self-signed certificate for HTTPS access.

I notice myself needing to go through the "Proceed anyway" prompt in Chrome once about every three days.

However, on my office router, it seems that I only need to do this around once per month.

What determines how long this exception lasts? I have refrained from clearing my cache for several weeks.

Comment: With the ability to get free certs (let's encrypt, etc.) there is no reason to use self signed certs.

Comment: Let'sEncrypt is not an option in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to suppress the browser telling you it is not trusted, make the certificate trusted. Put an issuing CA into your trusted store. Or get a certificate signed by a public CA.

There should be a straightforward way to issue certificates to dev just as there should be for production.